# Full text search on multiple columns sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
Id  Author
1   Alexander Mccall Smith
2   Ernest Hemingway
3   Giacomo Leopardi
4   Henry David Thoreau
5   Mary Higgins Clark
6   Rabindranath Tagore
7   Thomas Pynchon
8   Zora Neale Hurston
9   William S. Burroughs
10  Virginia Woolf
11  William tell
```

I want to search the Author by putting first few characters of the first and last name.

```
eg: Search Text: Will tel
Then the search result show the following result
```

**Will**iam **tel**l

```
eg: Search Text: will Burrou
Then the search result show the following result
```

**Will**iam S. **Burrou**ghs

eg: Search Text: Will
    Then the search result show the following result

**Will**iam S. Burroughs
**Will**iam tell

What is the efficient way to achieve this in sql server ?

Comment: as the title of your question seems to imply you know of full text search, you could use full text search?  Though I'm not sure how well it performs with nicknames and partial words... i know it works well with synonyms and filter words.  You might just need to use "like" if FTS doesn't suite your purposes.  Your question title implies a search on multiple columns, but the body of the question does not show this at all, kind of unclear.

Comment: If you can establish a general pattern of `Author` (like only one middle name and no prefix/suffix) you should be able to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: Any chance you rather have a parameter for first name and one for last name versus one parameter for the full text?

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned this can be achieved using Full Text Search. You have to create the FTS catalog and then index on the table and column(s). You stated in the title 'Columns' but I only see one table column in your example so I will create the queries using that.

```
-- example 1 searching on Will and Tel
SELECT Id, Author
FROM Authors
WHERE CONTAINS(Author, '"Will*" AND "tel*"')

-- example 2 searching on Will and Burrou
SELECT Id, Author
FROM Authors
WHERE CONTAINS(Author, '"will*" AND "Burrou*"')

-- example 3 searching on Will
SELECT Id, Author
FROM Authors
WHERE CONTAINS(Author, '"will*"')
```

For further reference see

- The [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) clause which searches for precise or fuzzy matches.
- Article [Query with Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Igor, I have been also looking for this kind of short explanation of FTS

Answer (score 0):

Less efficient than @Igor's answer as the table size grows, but you can also use the `Like` statement.

> The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

```
-- example 1 searching on Will and Tel
SELECT Id, Author
FROM Authors
WHERE Author Like('Will%Tel%')

-- example 2 searching on Will and Burrou
SELECT Id, Author
FROM Authors
WHERE Author Like('Will%Burrou%')

-- example 3 searching on Will
SELECT Id, Author
FROM Authors
WHERE Author Like('Will%')
```

Cons: It is slower than the contains statement.You need to include the `%` sign after any other keyword you're looking to search for.

Pros: Can be faster than contains statement in cases of smaller(<1000) row tables.