# How to make LIKE '%Search% faster in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a below query which is taking up a lot of time:-

```
 SELECT 
      p.CrmId,
      park.Name
 FROM
     Property p
 INNER JOIN
     Som som ON som.CrmId = p.SystemOfMeasurementId 
 LEFT JOIN
     Park park ON park.CrmId = p.ParkId
 WHERE 
     ((p.City like '%' + @search + '%' ) 
      OR (p.Address1 like '%' + @search + '%') 
      OR (p.Address2 like '%' + @search + '%' )
      OR (p.State like '%' + @search + '%' ) 
      OR (park.Name like '%' + @search + '%' ) 
      OR (p.ZipCode like '%' + @search + '%')
     )
     AND (@usOnly = 0 or (p.CrmCountryId = @USA_COUNTRY_ID))
```

I have read that indexes don't work well when we use `LIKE '%Search%`.

Any ideas on how to make this faster?

Comment: you are probably out of luck with that

Comment: You should look into something like [fulltext index/search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx), you will probably get better matching as well as speed.

Comment: Even with FTS it will be slow if you have a wild card word search in the beginning of your string. If you search the beginning of each word though with your search parameter then FTS can give you the speed you need. Example: @search with value Win should match address "123 Window lane" but not "123 LikWin". See this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38357262/1260204) as an example of how to write a query using FTS, you will need to construct the catalog and the index on the columns. You can also tweak how the index is populated / searched.

Comment: fulltext search is your only hope. When you use leading wildcards you eliminate the ability of an index to do a seek. Think about a phone book. If you want all last names that start with "S" it is pretty easy and fast to find. If you want all last names that contain "S" however....well you have to look at every single entry in the book to decide if it matches. This is a high level explanation of sql indexing.

Comment: @Igor FTS can be set to break on characters in addition to words for the index.

Comment: We had a similar issue with our app, we setup fulltext indexing on the searchable fields and saw big performance gains.

Comment: Are you using a leading wildcard because you are really searching for part of a city, i.e. `ondon` should return London, or is it because you field might contain leading spaces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right... queries with a leading wildcard are **awful** for performance. To get around this, Sql Server has something called [full text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). You create a special [FULL TEXT Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) for each of the columns you want to search, and then update your code to use the [CONTAINS keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  p.CrmId,
  park.Name
        from Property p
        inner join Som som on som.CrmId = p.SystemOfMeasurementId 
        left join Park park on park.CrmId = p.ParkId
  WHERE 
  (
       Contains(p.City, @search)
    or Contains(p.Address1, @search)
    or Contains(p.Address2, @search)
    or Contains(p.State, @search) 
    or Contains(park.Name, @search) 
    or Contains(p.ZipCode, @search)
 )
 AND (@usOnly = 0 or (p.CrmCountryId = @USA_COUNTRY_ID))
```

Unfortunately, all those OR conditions are still likely to make this pretty slow, and FULL TEXT wasn't intended as much for shorter strings like City or State, or for casting wide nets like this. You may find you'll do much better for this kind of search by integrating with a tool like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). In addition to writing a better and faster search, these tools will help you create sane rankings for returning results in an order that makes sense and is relevant to the input.

Another strategy it to create a computed column that concatenates your address and name text into a single column, and then do a single FULL TEXT index on that one field, with a single CONTAINS() call.

Comment: Your WHERE clause can be simplified to this: `CONTAINS((p.City, p.Address1, p.Address2, p.State, p.ZipCode), @search) OR CONTAINS(park.Name, @search)`.

Comment: `FREETEXT` is powerful than `CONTAINS()` but `CONTAINS()` is faster than that... your can use full text search and add `Stoplist` read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293825/full-text-index-stop-list-for-persian-language/61498895#61498895

Comment: A very important consideration germane to OP is `LIKE %query%` will match a substring anywhere in the field.  Full Text search, `FREETEXT`, `CONTAINS` does not offer this functionality.

Comment: @ttugates That's not true. `CONTAINS()` will also match a substring anywhere in the field. That's the whole reason it exists. What is more, CONTAINS() will still use an index, whereas `LIKE %query%` is almost always the absolute slowest way possible to accomplish the search.

Comment: I maintain the accuracy of my comment and disagree that its un-true.  I also disagree with the statement  " `CONTAINS()` will also match a substring anywhere in the field. That's the whole reason it exists. "
One SO with links to MS Documentation: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230064/full-text-search-only-performs-starts-with-searches.  
Disagreement aside, it is right and good to point users to Full Text Search.  I invite anyone in doubt to google `full text search for substring`

Answer (score 0):

This is old post, but in case someone has this issue, there is a good article on https://www.mssqltips.com/ on how to "cheat" using the REVERSE functionality. I think it's really clever and useful and it doesn't require a fulltext search:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5681/how-to-make-sql-server-wildcard-searches-faster/

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL FTS has 3 major limitations

1. suffix term (e.g. '"*abc"') not support
   you may run, but results are not correct
2. search exactly 'c x' from 'abc xyz' not support
   you may run, but results are not correct
3. correlated queries with contains/containstable not support --> this may be necessary when you want to find a set of keywords against a set of phrases/sentences

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).